# Ejabberd v24 compiled in erlang v24 throws "Can't set long node name!" error for cli commands

Tags: ejabberd, erlang

I have built an Ejabberd:v24 docker image with erlang:v24 base image and deployed in kubernetes cluster (k8s v1.26.2). Except "sbin/ejabberctl --node ejabberd@10.0.0.7 start" command, all other commands like "sbin/ejabberctl --node ejabberd@10.0.0.7 status", "sbin/ejabberctl --node ejabberd@10.0.0.7 stop", etc throws "Can't set long node name!" error and generates a crashdump file in the logs folder.

If anyone has faced this issue, please help in rectifying this.

Thanks in advance.

**Erlang_Version: v24**, **Ejabberd_Version: v24**, **Kubernetes_Version: v1.26.2**

**Error_Message:**

```
user@ejabberd:/# sbin/ejabberdctl --node ejabberd@10.0.0.7 stop

=INFO REPORT==== 21-Mar-2024::10:05:33.064535 ===
Can't set long node name!
Please check your configuration

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 21-Mar-2024::10:05:33.064570 ===
    supervisor: {local,net_sup}
    errorContext: start_error
    reason: {'EXIT',nodistribution}
    offender: [{pid,undefined},
               {id,net_kernel},
               {mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,
                                   [#{clean_halt => true,name => undefined,
                                      name_domain => longnames,
                                      supervisor => net_sup}]}},
               {restart_type,permanent},
               {significant,false},
               {shutdown,2000},
               {child_type,worker}]

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})

Crash dump is being written to: var/log/ejabberd/erl_crash.dump...done
```